# C - unexpected behavior in complex.h on different OS

Tags: c, clang, c99

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
int main()
{
   complex double aaa = INFINITY + 0*I;
   printf("%.f + %.f*I\n", creal(aaa), cimag(aaa));
   complex double bbb = 1.0/aaa;
   printf("%.f + %.f*I\n", creal(bbb), cimag(bbb));
   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compiling with `gcc -std=gnu99 -lm`, I expect that the output is

> inf + 0*I
>
> 0 + 0*I

which is true on Linux (tested on Scientific Linux 6.8 with gcc 4.4.7, Fedora 23 with gcc 5.3.1, and Ubuntu 14.04.5 with gcc 4.8.4).

However, on OS X (10.11.5 with clang-602.0.53) instead I get

> inf + 0*I
>
> nan + nan*I

It is obvious that clang does not conform the C99 standard (see [N1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf), Sec. G.5.1; strictly speaking, it's merely a recommended practice, not a standard). <s>In fact, clang does not have the macro `__STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__` defined, which is introduced in Sec. G.1.</s> Does clang purposely make this behavior? **UPDATE: after some checks I find several Linux environments that I tested do not have this macro defined either, but the code still works correctly there.**

Currently, my workaround for cross-platform support is to check the macro

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>
int main()
{
   complex double aaa = INFINITY + 0*I;
   printf("%.f + %.f*I\n", creal(aaa), cimag(aaa));
   complex double bbb = 1.0/aaa;
   #ifndef __STDC_IEC_559_COMPLEX__
   if(isnan(bbb)) 
   { 
      bbb = 0; //or do some trick that has to do with the problem context
   }
   #endif
   printf("%.f + %.f*I\n", creal(bbb), cimag(bbb));

   return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

But I'm not sure if it is robust...Any suggestion?

Comment: By [C standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.12p4): *INFINITY
expands to a constant expression of type float representing positive or unsigned infinity, if available; else to a positive constant of type float that overflows at translation time.* So it's behavior might not be identical across platforms...

Comment: @EugeneSh. 1. In this case `INFINITY` does expand to positive infinity, as can be checked by the 1st line of output, or in a debugger; 2. Here I write `INFINITY` simply to provide a MWE. You could have written something overflowing like `complex double aaa = 1.0/0.0;` without changing the conclusion; 3. It really doesn't make sense if this doesn't work because I've tested that a `double` counterpart does (replacing all `complex double` to `double`, taking away the functions `creal` and `cimag`, etc).

Comment: @LeoFang How it's handled mathematically and how `printf()` represents it may be not quite the same thing. Maybe the best way to determine if the problem really is `clang` or the architecture is by compiling it on OSX using `gcc`.

Comment: @Havenard, yes indeed it's not clear to me whether it's due to the architecture or compiler. I do use `gcc` to compile on OS X, although by default `gcc` is clang/LLVM. I'll try to use brew to get a true gcc later.

Comment: This seems to be an LLVM/Clang issue that was fixed in newer versions.  LLVM/Clang 3.6.2 (dating after `clang-602.0.53`) has the intended behavior while LLVM/Clang 3.5.2 has the described behavior.

Comment: @kdhp, you are right. Before posting I was testing on LLVM 3.6.0 (clang-602.0.53), and I just tested on another machine running OS X 10.10.5 with LLVM 3.7.0 (clang-700.1.81) which gives me the correct result. You may post an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are using %f instead of %lf for double arguments. It leads to unpredictable behavior, I think.